# How to connect MS Access Database over HTTP

Tags: vb.net, vb6, ms-access-2007

I want to convert my desktop application software to online application. I am using MS Access Database. I have seen some connection string and I applied in my application. Looks likes connection is open, but it will show this error :

> Internet Client Error: Cannot Connect to Server.

This is my Connection String : 
`"Provider=MS Remote;Remote Server= http://192.168.2.xxx; Remote Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\xxxxxx.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=yyyy;`

I don't know where I did mistake. So please give me an idea to clear this error.

Note : Currently I am working on same system as server.

Comment: There is a lot of administrative work to be done on the server to configure and enable RDS.  People were so sloppy about leaving it dangerously insecure that Microsoft had to leave it turned off at several levels starting with Windows XP or so.  Since then they've tried even harder to deprecate it, and the server-side libraries required do not even ship in Windows starting with Windows 8.  Few people use it anymore.

Comment: Looking at [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/), there doesn't appear to be an option for connecting to an Access database via HTTP. This makes me think it's either not possible, or not recommended. Also, vb6 or vb.net? It's not both as they are two different languages.

Comment: `MS Remote` + RDS allow HTTP connections but as intimated its a bad idea.  If this is a lan environment consider access over a UNC.

Comment: I am using VB.NET C-Pound guru... Which database is good for remote server?

Comment: Directly connecting to a remote C/S DBMS is not considered safe or viable either and you'll often face firewall hurdles as well.  This was the main reason why *what eventually became known as* web services came about.  Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc. expose an attack surface that most hosting companies don't want to deal with, so they block the associated ports from Internet access.

Answer (score 1):

The `Provider=MS Remote` (RDS) approach is deprecated. Here is a quote from the MSDN article

[Microsoft OLE DB Remoting Provider (ADO Service Provider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Important
>
> Beginning with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, RDS server components are no longer included in the Windows operating system (see Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 Compatibility Cookbook for more detail). RDS client components will be removed in a future version of Windows. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Applications that use RDS should migrate to WCF Data Service.

If you need to support a web-based application you should seriously consider using a different back-end database.